# Why does Inga turn into a woman?

Tags: un-go

In UN-GO Inga turns into a older female and people must answer her question. Is there a specific reason for the transformation? Or is there a deeper reason for the transformation?

> Inga has the mysterious ability to transform into an adult woman. When he has changed into this form, she can use her power that, when a question is asked, the victim has no choice to answer it with the truth. This ability has proven very useful in cracking cases, but difficulty is in asking which question so that the culprit will indeed be revealed.
>   Inga's power
>   BereisgreatAdded by Bereisgreat
>   When she uses her powers, she takes the head of the subject in her hands and asks her question. The light in the room start to flicker and Inga's eyes start glowing with pink lights. She somehow transforms again, this time into, what seems like, a corpse. Her eyes and mouth are wide open and are glowing with the same pink light. The corpse then falls apart in pink butterflies and those butterflies enter the mouth of the victim, after which he or she has no choice but to answer the question Inga asked, with the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you watch the Inga-ron OVA, they show that Inga is actually inhabiting the body of a woman who died to save Shinjurou when they first met. His body transforms back into hers when he uses his powers.

Comment: that explains most of it :D because he inhabits the dead body the moment he uses the power and transforms back in to her they see a corpse. as she is dead. Maybe you then also know why the butterflys come out of her mouth ?

Comment: sorry...not entirely sure about that. If I had to guess, it's probably some form of symbolism.